# How to provide a Guard for a specific Module in Nest.js?

Tags: nestjs

I have a module called `AdminModule` which should be protected by `AdminGuard`.

I tried to set up the Guard directly in the module like this:

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    HttpModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AdminController],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_GUARD,
      useClass: AdminGuard,
    },
    AdminService,
  ],
})
export class AdminModule {
}
```

However, the guard is not limited to this module but it is global (as stated in the docs: `"the guard is, in fact, global"`).

But how is it possible to make the guard only protect a module?

Answer (score 12):

Update : there is actually no options to achieve that.

Information :

What you've done by using `APP_GUARD` is to apply it globally. It's the same as using `useGlobalGuards`, but this way allows you to take advantage of the DI system.

```js
{
  provide: APP_GUARD,
  useClass: AdminGuard,
},
```

If you don't want to apply it globally, don't add this to the provider's array in the module.

Instead, just create a new guard like this

```js
@Injectable()
export class RolesGuard implements CanActivate {
  canActivate(
    context: ExecutionContext,
  ): boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean> {
    return true;
  }
}
```

See the documentation here: https://docs.nestjs.com/guards

And then apply it on your controller at the class level to impact all the handlers of the controller, or to a method to impact a specific endpoint.

```js
@UseGuards(RolesGuard)
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. The question want to apply guard to **specific** module, not public nor to controller.

Comment: Yeah and the answer is from 1.5 years ago, it wasn’t possible at that time. But I think it still not possible

Comment: I think you should update the answer with summary on the top kind of: "There is no way to apply ..."

Comment: Ok I have done an update, bit I am sure if it will be possible in 2 years someone will say that the answer is wrong even if it from few years ago. It already happened to me on other answer ahah

Comment: are there any updates on working with a specific module?

Comment: As of May 28, it doesn't seem to be in the core team's plans: https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/7193

Answer (score 4):

You can add `@UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)` before the controller class,and make the guard protect all routes on the controller.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem as you. I used a `Middleware` as a `Guard`.

```js
import { MiddlewareConsumer, Module, NestModule, RequestMethod } from '@nestjs/common';  
import { ApiModule } from './api/api.module';  
import { AdminGuardMiddleware } from './api/v1/admin/admin.guard.middleware';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ApiModule,
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer
      .apply(AdminGuardMiddleware)
      .forRoutes({ path: '/api/v1/admin/*', method: RequestMethod.ALL });
  }
}
```

**admin.guard.middleware.ts:**

```js
import { HttpException, HttpStatus, Injectable, NestMiddleware } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
    
@Injectable()
export class AdminGuardMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
        
    constructor() { }
    
    use(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
        try {
            // you can check anything here
            next();
    
        } catch (error) {
            throw new HttpException("invalid_request", HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit old, but there's a hacky way to do it in a controller level by declaring the controllers of a specific module. Guard context can access the type of the controller class the request is targeting. You can access it inside the guard itself.

```js
const PROTECTED_CONTROLLERS = [CatsController, SomeOtherController, UserController];

@Injectable()
export class JwtAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {
  constructor(private reflector: Reflector) {
    super();
  }

  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
    // this gets the controller class
    const controllerCls = context.getClass();

    if (!PROTECTED_CONTROLLERS.includes(controllerCls)) {
      // this guard is not important for context, so we should always allow request to continue
      return true;
    }

    // check if controller method contains @Public() decorator
    const isPublic = this.reflector.getAllAndOverride<boolean>(IS_PUBLIC, [
      context.getHandler(),
      controllerCls,
    ]);

    if (isPublic) {
      return true;
    }

    return super.canActivate(context);
  }
}
```

And then, you can add this guard as a global Guard like so:

```js
@Module({
  providers: [{ provide: APP_GUARD, useClass: JwtAuthGuard }]
})
export class MyModule {}
```

You should note that if you need other guards, the position in providers array is important

```js
@Module({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_GUARD,
      useClass: SomeOtherGuard, // <-- it will be executed first
    },
    {
      provide: APP_GUARD,
      useClass: JwtAuthGuard, // <-- it will be executed second if first guard passes
    },
})
export class MyModule {}
```

This is **not** a great way to do it and I recommend use decorators like the answers above. However, it can be useful in certain use cases where there's the need to have main modules and submodules in more complex applications.

If you are worried about verbosity of decorators on top of classes, you can use [decorator composition](https://docs.nestjs.com/custom-decorators#decorator-composition) for that.